# Python - Getting a 'TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()' after calling a function from a module

Tags: python, selenium

Python - Getting a 'TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()' after calling a function from a module

So, i'm building up a test suite, and i'm building up a Utility file with a bunch of reusable functions. One of these functions is a simple login function :

```
def Beta_login(driver, username, password):

driver.get("https://mywebsite.net")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
elem.send_keys(Keys, username)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
elem.send_keys(Keys, password)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "loginbutton submitter").click()

try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchinput"))
    )

finally:
    print ("Portal Page loaded Successfully")
```

Problem is, I get this error when I try to run this function through my Utility module:

```
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Funnily enough, if I were to place this functionality in the file that is calling this function, it ends up working just fine. Either my module is not being imported properly, or there is a problem in the called function itself.

Comment: What line in the code you've shown is producing that error? Can you post the full traceback? You mention calling something from a module, but it's not obvious what part of your code you're referring to. Can you show the import statements?

Answer (score 0):

thanks if you responded. I kept looking at it & I found the issue at hand.

elem.send_keys(Keys, username)

elem.send_keys(Keys, password)

These two lines were passing in Keys, when that isn't a part of the parameter list for that function, nor was Keys even declared yet. Thought i'd provide an answer to my own issue for the ppl who took a look at it. The program worked fine once I removed Keys as an argument.